# Ode23 doesn't finish executing

Tags: matlab

I'm new to Matlab, and I'm trying to solve the differential equation y'=-y/n for a constant n. I define the function in a script like this:

```
function dv = lc(v1)
dv = -v1/(0.0000047*0.000001);
```

And then try and solve it like this:

```
[t,v] = ode23('lc',[0 5],1)
```

But the operation never finishes executing. It just eats up my RAM and says "Busy" in the corner, until I press ctrl+c to terminate it. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the `n` that you are using?

Comment: @EliSadoff In my function it's 0.0000047*0.000001

Comment: Try with `n=0.2` and see if it does solve. It's possible that you are getting underflow.

Comment: @EliSadoff That works. What's underflow?

Comment: There aren't an infinite number of floating point numbers and sometimes, especially when using small floats, you'll get a number so small the computer will represent it as 0.

Comment: The process used by ode23 I believe is finite differencing and with underflow this can lead to a division by 0 error

Comment: @EliSadoff Thanks very much. Put that in an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're a victim of underflow. What happens is that there is not an infinite number of floating point numbers (see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)), so the results are not fully precise. When the numbers are small enough there is the possibility of the number being treated as `0` by the computer. The process that matlab uses for `ode23` is based on finite differencing, which involves division. Considering the underflow error, there either will be a division by `0` issue, or possible overflow with an incredibly small divisor trending the result toward infinity and not fulfilling the conditions for solution.